# Reading Android Permissions from Manifest through Native C

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, android-manifest, android-permissions

Is there a way to read android manifest permissions through Native C code? If its possible, can any one please provide an example.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to access all android permissions and their info from native code due complexity of java objects. But you can write a java method which fetches all this info and convert it to more simpler form like string array and return it. Then call this method in native code and use the return value for your use case. Just an idea never tried it.